# Generate code in code_128 format from another code

Tags: algorithm, code-generation, reverse-engineering, coupon, code128

I have a list of the following codes  and their corresponding codes in format code_128. I want to given a string, be able to generate the corresponging code in CODE_128 format. Based on this list, how could I generate a code_128 number to the string A4Y9387VY34, for example?

```
code                   code in code_128
A4Y9387VY34                 ????
ADN38Y644YT7     9611019020018632869509 
AXCW99QYTD34     9622019021500078083444 
A9YQC44W9J3K     9611083009710754539701 
AT8V7T3G3874     9622083021255845940154 
A7K444N4FKB8     9622083033510467186874 
AYCHFW448HTQ     9611005019246067403120 
AY63CWBMTDCC     9622005028182439033426 
ANY7TF46NGQ3     9622005031345848081170 
AYY48TBVQ3FH     9611200003793988696055 
AT8Q4CF4DQ9Q     9611200021606968867090 
A764WYQFJWTT     9622200022706968919275 
AC649ND7N8B6     9622148007265209832185 
A4VDPTJ99YN4     9611148013412173923039 
AHDYK498BD6T     9622148021309216149530 
A4YYYNY7C3DJ     9611017021934363499071 
AYG6XWVCCQ89     9622017031009914238743 
A68YJHGQKCCM     9622017031138587166053 
APMB7XG9XQC9     9611021011608391750002 
AGP8C44Y8VYK     9622021021608111646113 
A7C68B9T69XB     9622021021958603678086 
AJYYWKR6BDGN     9611010022528724015883 
AKMNVXDT9PYN     9622010027475034102229 
AXPXMK9QMDFD     9622010031475028243694
```

I read a lot about it, but I didn't come to any solution. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a pretty open question, I will give you my suggestions:

1. If it is a finite list, you can use a Hash or a Dictionary, where
   the keys are the Codes and map them to the corresponding value, in
   your case, Code_128
2. Some scanners have software installed that allow you to change what
   has been read to a new value, format it, etc.

If you need a bigger insight please, give us more detail about the environment you are using.
Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But I was thinking in some method or algorithm to given a code string, calculate the corresponding code in format code_128..

Comment: @Unknown, any specific format for Code? For example EAN13 (as I can see 12 digits there - thirteen could be the check digit)?

Comment: Apparently just a string that is composed of numbers and letters, but the size may be different than 12, such as string A4Y9387VY34 have size 11. But I think we could see these input codes as strings of EAN13 maybe.

Comment: From what I can gather there is a pattern for the first 4 numbers of the resulting string, the first two are 96 and the next two are either 11 or 22. But I do not know to what this is related.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create a new answer because now I get your point. Well, if you are talking about a GS1-128 Code (please see [www.gs1.org](http://www.gs1.org/)) please do not start without visiting [Wikipedia info about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128). as you can see, there is a thorough explanation about how to work with that type of code. That code is composed by several application identifiers followed by their corresponding values. There is a better way of encoding them by using special characters as parenthesis. [Here is other info](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/code-128/) that may help you.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edit the description, please see if it can help to see it in another way or if the way you suggested its really the correct. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, there are a couple of spellings there you should take care about. Also, if you think this answers your question, please mark my answer as the solution (checkmark)

Comment: Hi I edited again, thanks for your tips. But I still don't see an answer for what I am looking for. Thanks anyway.